# Is there a way to permanently rotate a pdf using the Google Chrome pdf viewer?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I know that you can right-click "rotate pdf", but when you save down the file or go to print, it's not rotated. Anyone know of a way to *permanently* rotate a pdf using Google's pdf viewer? Is there any way to write a script to add this feature to the pdf viewer?

Answer (score 7):

1. Open with Doc Hub in Google.
2. In top right corner there are three bars, click the bars.
3. Select Actions.
4. Rotate PDF.
5. Click Download/Export as PDF. 
   Document will be saved as rotated.

Answer (score 1):

*Using the default Chrome PDF Viewer has some limitations.*

When a PDF is open in Chrome, press Ctrl+P or get the Print Menu. In the Print options select 'Save as PDF' and in the orientation change from Portrait to Landscape. And then click on Print. This will rotate the entire PDF.

To specifically rotate one or two pages as far as I know can not be done using the default PDF Viewer. But you can always use a Chrome extension like this one here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dochub-edit-and-sign-pdf/adgncicbhbjfpijkdmbijninnhnmiblj

Comment: Chrome does not show the orientation setting anymore when printing a PDF. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Google Chrome Viewer specifically but I have used several other pdf programs. Every program I have used requires a Save or Save As to complete the rotation, so next time it's opened the rotation is already done.